# Sensio Framework Extra Bundle issues

Tags: symfony, composer-php, phpstorm

Symfony v 3.0.2
PHP 7
PHP Storm 10.0.3
OSX 10.11.2

Let me being by saying that I have never worked with Symfony before. My project manager and I after some research decided that it would fit the parameters of the project better than the other frameworks available.

While going through the video tutorials they mentioned using the Framework Extra Bundle in conjunction with annotations in order to make construction quicker and more effective which I would agree with but I can't seem to get the thing to work.

I followed the composer install directions to the letter and have verified in the kernel and the json file that it is referenced but still when I try to use the autocomplete feature in PHPStorm it's not happening.

Here is the AppKernel:

```php
public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        ];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }
```

```json
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0"
    },
```

As you can see it is everywhere it is supposed to be. However if I try to put a use statement in a file it gives me a warning which says Usage of Statement was not found and none of the autocompleting functions for the annotation are functioning as expected.

Thoughts?

Comment: *"However if I try to put a use statement in a file it gives me a warning which says Usage of Statement was not found"* Please provide screenshots -- the error + the place where this class is actually used.

Comment: Apparently it was a PHP Storm issue and not a Symfony issue. The video tutorial neglected to mention a plugin that should have been installed in PHP Storm to make use of this functionality.

Answer (score 4):

The plugin that needs to be installed is PHP Annotation. Below I've included a link to the repo.

https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-annotation-plugin